# How to get data from sqlite database that has been entered by user

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently trying to compare dates for a final year project. I want to be able to compare dates (from datepicker and calendarview) to see if they match and then only display the information for that given date.

I have tried:

```
String dateSelected = (dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TODAYS DATE" + dateSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), Calms.KEY_FLARE_DATE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

db = openOrCreateDatabase(Calms.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor c = null;

String dbDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calms.KEY_FLARE_DATE));
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), dbDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I am at a real loss here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: give http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html this tutorial a go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read some tutorial to find out how to query databases.

The following would give you all columns in all records of some table:

```
Cursor c = db.query("SomeTable", null,
                    null, null, null, null, null);
```

To get only the records with some specific date, add a where clause:

```
Cursor c = db.query("SomeTable", null,
                    KEY_FLARE_DATE + " = ?",
                    new String[] { dateSelected },
                    null, null, null);
```